# Angular 4 doesn't care about the Elvis operator (?.)

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

Elvis operator (also known as the safe navigation operator) is supposed to avoid crashing pages when trying to access to "undefined" methods in JavaScript objects, right?

Well, maybe not, maybe I'm doing something wrong. Check this code out:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <h3>"{{place?.get("placeName")}}" management</h3>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let visit of visitBuffer">
      User: {{visit?.get("userId")}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

(yes, it's an Ionic app, which runs Angular 4).

So I'm trying just to see the userId of each object "visit" for each item. Should not be a problem, right? I load all the info of visitBuffer in two different, parallel queries, that run in the constructor:

```
export class Management {

  place;
  visitBuffer = [];

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams
  ) {
    const placeId = localStorage.getItem("placeId");
    this.getPlace(placeId)
        .then( place => {
          this.place = place;
          // Subscribe to normal Visits
          this.subscribeVisits(placeId).then( subscription => {
            let s = <any> subscription;
            s.on('create', (visit) => {
              this.visitBuffer.push(visit);
            });
          })
          // Subscribe to GroupVisits
          this.subscribeGroupVisits(placeId).then( subscription => {
            let s = <any> subscription;
            s.on('create', (visit) => {
              this.visitBuffer.push(visit);
            });
          })
        })
  }
```

The methods you see there, just query to the Parse database and return some objects or arrays. They just push the objects into "visitBuffer" and apply a .map function to the arrays, reasigning their data into the same "visitBuffer" array than before. This is used so two similar objects (Visits and VisitGroups) enter in the same array, since I'm going to work equally with them in my view.

I'm just trying to get the Parse method ".get(property)", so I can get the property usedId that both type of objects have. And I'm even using the elvis operator, but... it will throw errors anyways:

```
VM1194 Management.ngfactory.js:13 ERROR TypeError: _v.context.$implicit.get is not a function
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (VM174 Management.ngfactory.js:15)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (VM82 vendor.js:13488)
    at checkAndUpdateView (VM82 vendor.js:12632)
    at callViewAction (VM82 vendor.js:12995)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (VM82 vendor.js:12953)
    at checkAndUpdateView (VM82 vendor.js:12628)
    at callViewAction (VM82 vendor.js:12995)
    at execComponentViewsAction (VM82 vendor.js:12927)
    at checkAndUpdateView (VM82 vendor.js:12633)
    at callViewAction (VM82 vendor.js:12995)
```

Am I doing something wrong...? Why the view crashes when I'm using the elvis operator?

Comment: What is `place` actually? This error points more to that there is no `get` method for `place`. Which would be correct, since `place` is "just a variable".

Comment: @AJT_82 the fail isn't happening with the place object, but with the visitBuffer object

Comment: Well, what is `visit` then? It seems to be "just a variable too"?

Comment: Minor point, but `?:` is the Elvis operator and is a form of the null-coalescing operator. AFAIK `?.` doesn't have a fun name, but its name within Angular is the "safe navigation operator".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed the problem, though there is an interesting fact I just realised, about the Elvis operator.

The variable I was aiming at (usedId), didn't exist for the type "GroupVisit", so when one object of that type arrived, it crashed. Thing is, it seems that the elvis operator seems to check the type of the variable first, and then, apply the same rule for every value that comes from the array.

I thought that the elvis operator would check the null values in every object, but it just does at the first, as it seems. I had to make some changes at how I populate "visitBuffer" so I don't get that problem anymore: I could use different arrays, or just adding the property to the GroupVisit objects. This second option worked good.

Anyways, for situations like this, in which we have a dynamically typed array, we should have some type of "looped elvis operator" that checks the null value in each iteration of the loop, instead of just for the first object.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue in the past. See if `*ngIf` helps:

```
 <ion-list *ngIf="visitBuffer">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let visit of visitBuffer">
      User: {{visit.get("userId")}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Comment: This may sound strange, but... it's failing even with the ngIf. Maybe it's because my visitBuffer is initialized to []?

Comment: There is actually no need for the ngIf unless you really wish to hide the ion-list.
The ngFor will loop once items are there so if it is an empty list, nothing will be shown anyway.


@Zerok, the fastest way to check this is to run !![] somewhere and log the output. This will output true so indeed is it because of the initialization